# Is there a way of making the active tab a inline border in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I style the active tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To replicate that image, all you need is a theme. If you're on a Mac (apple product), type `Cmd + K` then `Cmd + T`. Then in the search bar for the color theme, type "Dark High Contrast". You'll see a color theme called "Dark High Contrast". Click on that, and there you go.

Comment: Bravo! You really help me a lot!

Comment: @evan1783 - There is a checkmark under the two arrows under the zero of this answer. If this answer help you, clicking the checkmark will "accept" the answer and let people know that this question has been sufficiently answered.

Comment: I've removed the video now, sorry, hopefully (for anyone else) the above helps.